# What are Verbose Errors

Tags: vb.net, wcf-data-services

I came across the following in a WCF Service I was working on and at no point have I either coded this in or seen it there before.

```
#If DEBUG Then
    config.UseVerboseErrors = True
#End If
```

What does this do and where could it have come from

Note - no one else has access to my work.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, verbose errors are supplied with the name of the unhandled exception and a stack trace showing where the error occurred in the first place, usually accompanied by a line number and file name.

A developer would want to see that sort of stuff while debugging or testing (debugging=true) but you would probably want a user to see a friendlier error message, or at least less low-level information, without giving away any architectural clues that might guide a would-be intruder,

They originate from your run-time environment during execution.

This is true to the definition of verbose which is:

"Using or expressed in more words than are needed"